# xarray groupby does not drop dimension when squeeze

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, pandas-groupby, python-xarray

I have MxNxT xarray with the following dimensions and coordinates:

```
<xarray.DataArray (gridcell: 238, window: 9, traits: 3)>
dask.array<where, shape=(238, 9, 3), dtype=float32, chunksize=(14, 9, 3), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
Coordinates:
    band         (traits) int32 dask.array<chunksize=(3,), meta=np.ndarray>
    spatial_ref  int32 0
  * traits       (traits) <U7 'trait_1' 'trait_2' 'trait_3'
  * gridcell     (gridcell) MultiIndex
  - latitude     (gridcell) float64 6.054e+06 6.054e+06 ... 6.054e+06 6.054e+06
  - longitude    (gridcell) float64 6.042e+05 6.043e+05 ... 6.043e+05 6.043e+05
  * window       (window) MultiIndex
  - x_window     (window) int64 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2
  - y_window     (window) int64 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2
Attributes:
    scale_factor:  1.0
    add_offset:    0.0
```

I am trying to apply groupby the "gridcell" dimension so I can perform an operation on each of those groups using xr.map or apply_ufunc function.

```
kernel_group = kernels_xr.groupby('gridcell', squeeze=True)
```

When I do that, the resulting group matrix is 1xNxT, but I only want groups to be NxT, isn't that what squeeze is supposed to do? I don't see any changes whatsoever. Your help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Would be good if you could provide a reproducible example. In absence of it, did you try running `.squeeze()` after the `groupby`?